# Volley library ignoring format=feed&type=rss Params

Tags: android, rss, android-volley

I need to get rss feed using Volley library but Volley keeps ignoring my `format=feed&type=rss` Params.
I tried every thing but i couldn't get it work.
Here is my URL: `http://almesryoon.com/%D8%AF%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%86?format=feed&type=rss`
**Note: this URL is working on Google PostMan**
My `SimpleXmlRequest` Class:

```
public class SimpleXmlRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    private static final Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Listener<T> listener;


    /**
     * Make HTTP request and return a parsed object from Response
     * Invokes the other constructor.
     *
     * @see SimpleXmlRequest#SimpleXmlRequest(int, String, Class, Map, Listener, ErrorListener)
     */
    public SimpleXmlRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,
                            Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(method, url, clazz, null, listener, errorListener);
    }


    /**
     * Make HTTP request and return a parsed object from XML Response
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     * @param listener
     * @param errorListener
     *
     */
    public SimpleXmlRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                            Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }


    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/xml";
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        try {

            String data = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));// The problem here this data is not XML

            return Response.success(serializer.read(clazz, data),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new VolleyError(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Also i tried to make it using `METHOD.POST` with `getParams()` method
Target `rss`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- generator="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" -->
<rss version="2.0" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <description>Description</description>
        <link>http://google.com</link>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 31 Mar 2016 01:27:12 +0200</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Joomla! - Open Source Content Management</generator>
        <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://example.com/example?format=feed&amp;type=rss"/>
        <language>ar-aa</language>
        <item>
            <title>Item1</title>
            <link>http://example.com/example1</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://example.com/example1</guid>
            <description>Description1</description>
            <author>admin</author>
            <category>Category1</category>
            <pubDate>Wed, 30 Mar 2016 18:49:37 +0200</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Item2</title>
            <link>http://example.com/example2</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://example.com/example2</guid>
            <description>Description2</description>
            <author>admin</author>
            <category>Category1</category>
            <pubDate>Wed, 30 Mar 2016 18:49:37 +0200</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I was using this code and it was working perfectly but `HttpParams`, `BasicHttpParams`, `HttpConnectionParams`, `DefaultHttpClient`, `HttpGet`, `HttpResponse` and `HttpEntity` are deprecated now.
My working code:

```
StringBuilder chaine = new StringBuilder("");

        try {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
            // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
            int timeoutConnection = AppConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = AppConstants.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                chaine.append(line);

            }

            rd.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962904/volley-library-for-android-parse-xml-response yet?

Comment: Yes but didn't help. The problem is not about parsing, it's about request.

Comment: I guess that this issue is because of your URL having Arabic characters, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614048/volley-sending-request-as-utf-8 to see if it can help or not. Try something such as `URLEncoder` or `Uri.encode()`

Comment: @BNK No it's not about encoding volley just ignore the URL parameters i don't know why. Now i'm using Retrofit and everything is working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following url to get your required RSS

```
https://m.almesryoon.com/%d8%af%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%b1-%d8%a3%d8%ad%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b7%d9%86?format=feed&type=rss&template=mobile
```

Here is the log:

```
...
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 27K, 12% free 6432K/7303K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
I/onResponse: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <!-- generator="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" -->
              <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
                <channel>
                    <title>دفتر أحوال الوطن - المصريون</title>
                    <description>المصريون صحيفة يومية مستقلة تنشر آخر وأهم أخبار مصر والوطن العربى والعالم</description>
                    <link>https://m.almesryoon.com/دفتر-أحوال-الوطن</link>
                    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:36:51 +0200</lastBuildDate>
                    <generator>Joomla! - Open Source Content Management</generator>
                    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://m.almesryoon.com/دفتر-أحوال-الوطن?format=feed&amp;type=rss&amp;template=mobile"/>
                    <language>ar-aa</language>
                    <item>
                    ...
```

---

After testing some sample code with your server url, I have found that it got 301 response. From your first url, the second url will be (**https**)

```
https://almesryoon.com/%D8%AF%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%86?format=feed&type=rss
```

The 3rd url will be:

```
http://m.almesryoon.com/%d8%af%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%b1-%d8%a3%d8%ad%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b7%d9%86?template=mobile
```

And the final url will be (**https**):

```
https://m.almesryoon.com/%d8%af%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%b1-%d8%a3%d8%ad%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b7%d9%86?template=mobile
```

With this final url and the sample code below, you will get **200** response code. I think you can try your code with the final url I mentioned above.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "https://m.almesryoon.com/%d8%af%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%b1-%d8%a3%d8%ad%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b7%d9%86?template=mobile";
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.i("onResponse", response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
    }
});

queue.add(request);
```

About handling 301 response in Volley, I have not tried, however, you can read the following question for more information

[Android volley to handle redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481964/android-volley-to-handle-redirect)

Comment: But the final URL that you mentioned above is leading to a normal web page not the required RSS link.

Comment: Pls use the new url `https://m.almesryoon.com/%d8%af%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%b1-%d8%a3%d8%ad%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b7%d9%86?format=feed&type=rss&template=mobile`, your app will get required RSS content, I have checked and updated my answer

Comment: I don't have time now to try it but i think it will work. Please try to explain why we have to add `template=mobile` to get it work using volley. BTW i'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: I think Volley does not handle 301/302 resp code. If I have time, i will check OkHttp or Retrofit for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried encoding your URL and it didn't work, the problem is with volley . Unfortunately , I have encountered the same situation only with POST requests made with volley. They worked flawless with the HTTP implementation but returned 400 with volley.My solution at that time was to stick with the old HTTP implementation.

Comment: Yes i know that but i need to know why ?

Comment: Some bugs in the Volley library i assume. I couldn't find the answer.